# Change foreach $key variable inside the foreach loop

Tags: php, variables

Looking for a way to change `$$key` to something like `$$key_error`so the variable will look something like: `$name_error` outside the foreach loop.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $$key = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $value));
     if (empty($value)) {
       // change variable below to something like $$key_error ($$name_error)
       $$key = 'is-invalid';

     } else {
       $$key = "value='$value'";
     }
  }
```

When an input is empty the user will return to the registration form, the input that is empty will have red bootstrap borders. When a field is not empty, the value will still be there so they do not have to do it all over.

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-lg <?=$name?>" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="Voor- en achternaam" <?=$name?>>
```

I hope it all makes sense :)

Comment: Why?  Anytime you use variable variables you should probably be using an array, which you already are using.  Or build another `$errors` array.

Comment: Could you clarify that for me?

Comment: @Niels `$errors[$key] = <error relative to that key here>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrays.

```
$errors = [];
$values = [];

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // validation check for $value
    if (/*validation check fails*/) {
       $errors[$key] = 'error message specific to this field';
    } else {
        $values[$key] = htmlspecialchars($value);
    }
}
```

Then in your form, check for the array key matching your control name.

```
<input type="text" name="example"
    class="<?= isset($errors['example']) ? 'is-invalid' : '' ?> other classes"
    value="<?= $values['example'] ?? '' ?>">
```

You can also output the specific error message if you want to.

```
<div class="error"><?= $errors['example'] ?? '' ?></div>
```